# How to fix infinite loop of redirects from http to https on nginx for WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, nginx, https

I need help. `Nginx`, frontend web server,  by default redirects from

```
http -> https.
```

WordPress falsely redirects from some reason from `https -> http`
It creates an infinite loop.

I have a clean WordPress installation, with default .htaccess.

On the site's database, `wp_options` table's siteurl, home are set to https.

What have I forgotten? Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you are not clear if the issue is coming from NGINX or from WORDPRESS. So the first thing would be troubleshooting wordpress:

Here are the troubleshooting steps (check the site after each one is done):
1. Rename .htaccess
2. Rename the plugins folder
3. If renaming the plugins folder does the trick, then look for any plugin causing the issue 
4. Delete /wp-content/cache folder if exists.

For NGINX troubleshooting:
Execute this command, and locate the virtualhosts affecting the site
apache2ctl -S   [On Debian/Ubuntu]
apachectl -S    [On CentOS/RHEL]
OR
httpd -S

Paste the virtualhosts so I can see if something is wrong.